# Line breaks between blocks in function expressions in Javascript

Tags: regex, ide, line-breaks

I have the following code

```
$scope.someMethod = function () {
    // code
}
$scope.someOtherMethod = function () {
    // code
}
$scope.randomMethod = function () {
    // code
}
```

I would like to make it to be:

```
$scope.someMethod = function () {
   // code
}

$scope.someOtherMethod = function () {
   // code
}

$scope.randomMethod = function () {
    // code
}
```

Is there any IDE, Text Editor or RegEX to add this line breaks? Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: A find/replace on `}\n$` to `}\n\n$` should do it. Most IDEs and good text editors can do that.

Comment: There is also http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This regex will do the following:

- find all lines that start with `$scope` and contain `function`
- insert an empty line in front of these lines

Note there are a ton of edge cases that will trip this type of expression.

The Regex:

```
^(\$scope[.](?:(?!\n).)*?function)
```

Replace with:

```
\n$1
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Examples

**Live Example**

https://repl.it/CLkb/1

**Javascript Code**

```
var Regex = new RegExp("^(\\\$scope[.](?:(?!\n).)*?function)" ,"mg" )   
var SourceString = `
$scope.someMethod = function () { 
    // code 
}
$scope.someOtherMethod = function () {
    // code
}
$scope.randomMethod = function () {
    // code
}
`

var Result = SourceString.replace(Regex, "\n$1");

console.log(SourceString)
console.log()
console.log(Result)
```

**Sample Output**

```
$scope.someMethod = function () { 
    // code 
}
$scope.someOtherMethod = function () {
    // code
}
$scope.randomMethod = function () {
    // code
}


$scope.someMethod = function () { 
    // code 
}

$scope.someOtherMethod = function () {
    // code
}

$scope.randomMethod = function () {
    // code
}
```